# Table Partitioning

Tags: sql, database-partitioning

How advantageous is it to use partitioning of tables as compared to normal approach?

Is there a sort of sample case or detailed comparative analysis that could statistically (I know this is too strong a word, but it would really help if it is illustrated by some numbers) emphasise on the utility of the process.

Answer (score 2):

Partitioning is extremely powerful, and is really dividing a tables data into several smaller tables - then unifying them by using a view.

For instance, 'ipnumbers' could be  divided into the tables 'ipnumbers_1', 'ipnumbers_2' and 'ipnumbers_3', where the first table contains constraints so that only ipnumbers ranging from 0.0.0.0 - 50.0.0.0 are stored, and the second table contains constraints allowing only to store ranges 50.0.0.1 to 100.0.0.0, etc. Then a view could be added that unifies the partitioned tables into one:

```
SELECT * FROM ipnumbers_1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM ipnumbers_2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM ipnumbers_3
```

Now, when you query the view for a certain ipnumber:

```
SELECT * FROM ipnumberview WHERE ipno=60.0.0.1
```

..The SQL server query optimizer will know that only the table 'ipnumbers_2' must be checked, and you thus gain a massive speed improvement.

Also, schemabound views can be inserted into (automatically placing data in the correct destination table), and tables can be placed on different servers (although this is a little tricky to setup), and you can also add indexes to views.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You might read all the way through

[this](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/performance-partitioning.html) and [this](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/testing-partitions-large-db.html)

Even though the articles are mysql specific, and all performance wise conclusions should not be blindly taken if you work on a different DBMS, still the articles nicely describe basic concepts and ideas together with some real numbers and examples.